# Magento 2. How to create new uiComponent(e.g. my_customer_form) that extends from existing one(customer_form)?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

In this context we use the term UiComponent to define a configured collection of components to create a form or a listing, for example customer_form which is configured in customer_form.xml

How can I create a new uiComponent(e.g. my_customer_form) that extends from existing one(customer_form)?

I'm 90% percent sure there is a way to inherit from existing uiComponents but i can't remember what is the syntax.

For example in my component to write:

```
<form>
...
<some_special_node>customer_form<some_special_node>
...
</form>
```

As a result my new uiComponent has everything the customer_form has and I can add new fields.

Any tips are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. All you have to do is add the extends="parent_name" attribute to the listing or form node as follows:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         extends="parent_listing_componnt"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
```